# Compare Marks field at a row level

Tags: mysql

I have below set of data from TableA

```
S.No  StudentID      Marks  Description  SubjectID
1             1        50   Science      1
2             1        30   Mathematics  2
3             2        25   Science      1
4             2        25   Mathematics  2
```

I wanted to run a query and to compare marks between Science and Mathematics and get students only who scored greater marks than Mathematics. And I should not see the student who scored same marks in both subjects.

Output:

```
S.No  StudentID      Marks  Description  SubjectID
1             1        50   Science      1
2             1        30   Mathematics  2
```

Can someone please help me with a sample query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you have any  subject(s) other than mentioned in question?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done but with a the lengthy way but i am sure there will be another good solution for this

```
select a.*
from demo a
join(
select t.StudentID
from demo t
join demo t1 on t.StudentID = t1.StudentID
and t.Description = 'Science'
and t1.Description = 'Mathematics'
and t.Marks > t1.Marks) b using(StudentID);
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e44c7/17)

Comment: Does it make any impact on performance of query if you use SubjectID instead of description in both AND conditions?

Comment: Yes can use relevant subject ids, for above query i can suggest to have a composite index on index(StudentID,Description ,Marks )